# Orchard alternates based on Tag

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I want to create alternates for content item based on its tag value.

For example, I want to create an alternate called `List-ProjectionPage-tags-special`

Searching the nets directs me to implement a new `ShapeDisplayEvents`

Thus, I have

```
public class TagAlternatesFactory : ShapeDisplayEvents
{
    public TagAlternatesFactory()
    {
    }

    public override void Displaying(ShapeDisplayingContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

In the `Displaying` method, I believe I need to check the contentItem off the context.Shape and create an alternate name based off of that (assuming it has the TagsPart added to the content item).

However, what do I do with it then? How do I add the name of the alternate? And is that all that's needed to create a new alternate type? Will orchard know to look for `List-ProjectionPage-tags-special`?

Comment: What do you do if there is more than one tag? One alternate per tag? Did you check the code from other classes that add alternates?

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy I'm going with one alternate per tag ATM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a cue from Bertrand's comment and looked at some Orchard source for direction.

Here's my implementation:

```
public class TagAlternatesFactory : ShapeDisplayEvents
{
    public override void Displaying(ShapeDisplayingContext context)
    {
        context.ShapeMetadata.OnDisplaying(displayedContext =>
        {
            var contentItem = displayedContext.Shape.ContentItem;
            var contentType = contentItem.ContentType;

            var parts = contentItem.Parts as IEnumerable<ContentPart>;
            if (parts == null) return;

            var tagsPart = parts.FirstOrDefault(part => part is TagsPart) as TagsPart;
            if (tagsPart == null) return;

            foreach (var tag in tagsPart.CurrentTags)
            {
                displayedContext.ShapeMetadata.Alternates.Add(
                                    String.Format("{0}__{1}__{2}__{3}", 
displayedContext.ShapeMetadata.Type, (string)contentType, "tag", tag.TagName)); //See update
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This allows an alternate view based on a tag value. So, if you have a project page that you want to apply a specific style to, you can simply create your alternate view with the name `ProjectionPage_tag_special` and anytime you want a projection page to use it, just add the `special` tag to it.

**Update**
I added the `displayedContext.ShapeMetadata.Type` to the alternate name so specific shapes could be overridden (like the List-ProjectionPage)